# Make Dynamic Variable Available to Multiple Chef Recipes

Tags: ruby, variables, chef-infra

We dynamically compute the name of a directory at run-time from some attributes:

```
var1 = (node['foo']['bar']).to_s
var2 = (node['foo']['baz']).to_s
app_dir = "/var/#{var1}/#{var2}
```

Copying this code block to all of the recipes that needs it works. When we have tried to clean this up, it bombs with "No resource, or local variable named 'app_dir'.

We have tried the following:

1) Move the block of code into attributes/default.rb

2) Move the block of code into recipes/default.rb

3) Same as 2 above, but adding `require_relative 'default'` in the recipes that require the variable

Answer (score 0):

If you're requiring from a separate file (e.g. require_relative) you need to make the variable something that gets exported. You can try making it a constant instead e.g. `AppDir =`, or a method. Local variables are not loaded with require.

Comment: What makes it a constant? Camel-casing the variable?

Comment: It's not camel case, it's the fact that it starts with a capital letter. Classes and modules are also constants, that's why they start with capitals too e.g. `class Foo; Bar = 1; end` defines `Foo::Bar`

Comment: This is not relevant to Chef, please remove it.

Comment: @coderanger who are you speaking to? and what should be removed?

Comment: This answer is general, it's correct from a general Rubyist PoV but Chef has some specific restrictions that make it more complex :-)

Comment: @coderanger like what? Why specifically would this not work?

Comment: So one is that `require` doesn't work at all in that context in a useful way because attribute files run as an `instance_eval` against one of Chef's main data objects (the node) while recipes eval against unique `Chef::Recipe` objects. Creating consts would result in nested names because of that, which most users wouldn't expect or understand. Your answer is correct from a plain Ruby top-level context but as I said, Chef is not like that.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a good way to do this in Chef. Recipe and attributes files run in very different contexts so your best bet is either copy-pasta the boiler plate (if it really is as small as your example, do that) or otherwise maybe a global helper method but those are hard to write safely. Ping me on Slack and we can talk about the right kind of helper method for your exact situation (covering all of them isn't really practical for an SO answer).

Comment: I think that you are right about the amount of effort - I've spent too much time and need to get back to the more important parts of the cookbook / recipes. If you have a link to something that is already written about helper methods I'd be interested in reading it later when I've gotten this all worked out. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I've been meaning to write one, but haven't gotten to it yet. Modifying the DSL with new global methods is unfortunately very tricky. I do have a prototype project called poise-dsl to try and simplify it, but I'm not sure it would help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to share some code between a bunch of different recipes, you can try using [a library](https://docs.chef.io/libraries.html) loaded from a common cookbook dependency.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, doing this in a way that works with attribute files is very tricky.

Comment: @coderanger Yes, that's true, but from my reading of OP's question, it looks like they just want this code available to their recipe files, not their attributes files.